# SQL How can I return 2 different dates in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a query and what I want to do is return the latest date for 2 columns in the same row. If you look at RowID 1 & 2 I would like to merge both rows. They both have the same Event Type however where they differ is in the **isProcessed** column one contains 1 and the other 0 value. The **LastReceived** column should return the latest date where isProcessed is 0 and the **LastProcessed** column should return the last date where IsProcessed is 1. Right now I have that working but it returns in 2 rows. Row 1 shows the last date of where LastReceived is 0 and Row 2 shows the last date where Lastprocessed is 1. Both LastReceived and LastProcessed come from the column **CreatedOn**. What I somehow need to do is something like this in the select clause

```
select MAX(select CreatedOn from mytable where IsProcessed=1) as LastProcessed,
MAX(select CreatedOn from mytable where IsProcessed=0) as LastReceived
```

This is my query below

```
with cte as (select distinct EventType,SendingOrganizationID,MAX(CreatedOn) as LastReceived,MAX(CreatedOn) as LastProcessed,case 
when SendingOrganizationID = '3yst8' then 'Example 1'
else 'Client Not Found'
END AS ClientName,IsProcessed from mytable
where  isprocessed in(0,1)
group by SendingOrganizationID,EventType,IsProcessed
having datediff(hour, MAX(CreatedOn), getdate()) >= 9)

Select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY SendingOrganizationID) as RowID,* from cte order by SendingOrganizationID,EventType,IsProcessed
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be great

Comment: I think I would try an outer or cross apply.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case when:

```
select EventType,SendingOrganizationID,
MAX(case when isProcessed = 0 then CreatedOn end) as LastReceived,
MAX(case when isProcessed = 1 then CreatedOn end) as LastProcessed
from mytable
group by SendingOrganizationID,EventType;
```